# Cognito Trigger not working for Federated sigin

Tags: amazon-web-services, triggers, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, federated

I have configured a lambda trigger for Cognito. It works well for Cognito user signin but not for federated user sign in. 
Note: I am not using the 'Cognito Hosted UI' but Auth.federatedSignIn so that the users are authenticated via the provider(eg: google).

Previously i did add-permission for the Cognito. Like below.

aws lambda add-permission

--function-name

--statement-id

--action lambda:InvokeFunction

--principal cognito-idp.amazonaws.com

--source-arn

Should I do the same with 'principal' being google? I tried 'accounts.google.com'. It didn't work.

I am not sure why the trigger doesn't work for federated users.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the User Pool triggers are for User Pool users (via Email/Username), and not for the Identity Pool federated users... Did you ever get this to work? Can you confirm please?

Comment: Yes, I got it to work. I had to use 'Identity pool'.

Comment: can you please further explain how to achieve that ?

Comment: @umer you have to create 'Identity Pool' and create roles (authenticated & unauthenticated) and then choose Authentication providers(google, facebook etc.)

Comment: client side,eg: google
const ga = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
ga.signIn().then(
            googleUser => {
             const {id_token, expires_at} = googleUser.getAuthResponse();
        const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        let user = {
            email: profile.getEmail(),
            name: profile.getName()
        };

        const credentials = await Auth.federatedSignIn(
            'google',
            {token: id_token, expires_at},
            user
        );
            },
            error => {
             
            }
        );